По какой причине скрипт падает не выдавая ошибку?
Есть такой скрипт:
const initCycleTLS = require('cycletls');
(async () => {
    let arr = new Array(5000).fill(1);
    let promises = arr.map(async () => {
        let cycleTLS = await initCycleTLS().catch(error => console.log('Init CycleTLS error: ' + error));
        if (typeof cycleTLS === 'function')
        {
            await cycleTLS('https://google.com').catch(error => console.log('Request error: ' + error));
            await cycleTLS.exit().catch(error => console.log('Exit CycleTLS error: ' + error));
        }
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log('DONE');
})();

При запуске с массивом arr с небольшой длиной все работает нормально, скрипт выводит "DONE" в конце, но при запуске с большим массивом, как в примере он падает молча, либо выдает инфу из catch, но до "DONE" не доходит, хотя все исключения отлавливаются. В чем может быть причина?
P.S. Я знаю что библиотеку нужно использовать иначе, это искусственный пример в котором происходит какой-то совершенно новый для меня баг, понимание которого нужно для образовательных и познавательных целей.

Я могу ошибаться, но попробуй из arr.map сделать arr?.map

@VeekSY , неа не помогает(

В разделе Пример множественных запросов для Typescript и Javascript показано как использовать экземпляр CycleTLS правильно, на сколько я понимаю - он должен быть единственным:
(async () => {
  const cycleTLS = await initCycleTLS();
  const promises = (new Array(5)).fill(1).map(
    () => cycleTLS('https://google.com', {}, 'get'),
  );
  await Promise.all(promises);
  await cycleTLS.exit();
})().catch(console.error).finally(() => console.log('DONE'));


Да я согласен, так правильно, я поэтому в PS об этом сказал, тут вопрос даже не в самой либе, а том как рождаются такие баги, которые даже не отследить.

это вопрос к автору. я думаю в этой библиотеке есть странности в организации обмена данными, почитайте checkSpawnedInstance, spawnServer, handleSpawn  https://github.com/Danny-Dasilva/CycleTLS/blob/main/src/index.ts

спасибо, годный совет, я вчера весь день эту лигу вдоль и поперек прошел, вставляя свои метки вывода в консоль, чтобы понять до куда скрипт доходит докуда нет, и понял что если не делать request или не делать exit, что то одно из двух то отрабатывает нормально.

Я даже на фрилансе выложил задачу за оплату, если вам интересно, то можете попробовать сами.

я не анализировал тщательно код, но по всему выходит так, что при каждом вызове initCycleTLS, инстансируется класс Golang с одним и тем же значением порта и всё это хозяйство начинает друг другу мешать

да все верно, демон прокси сервер один, но инстантов много... Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда можно копать, чтобы увидеть ошибку, если ли какие нибудь у Ноды средства, флаги там или тп, чтобы сделать все прозрачным. И вообще может ли быть такое что сама Нода производит низкоуровневую ошибку которую нельзя выбросить в консоль?
